# Do you need to specify ISOs as being bootable?

Tags: iso-image, burning, bootable-media

Say you download an ISO you want to boot from. Are you guaranteed that it is bootable or must you know whether or not to specify additional settings in the disk burning software to make it bootable or not? In other words is the information whether the disk is bootable or not built into ISOs?

Comment: In my experience, no.  On a side note, instead of burning bootable ISOs to a CD-R/DVD-R, you can use a USB flash drive and a utility such as [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).

Comment: +1 for the link to Rufus, looks like it'll save a lot of time as I no longer have to faff around with `diskpart` when putting a Windows ISO onto a USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image):

> ISO disc images are uncompressed and do not use a particular container format; they are a sector-by-sector copy of the data on an optical disc, stored inside a binary file. ISO images are expected to contain the binary image of an optical media file system (usually ISO 9660 and its extensions or UDF), including the data in its files in binary format, copied exactly as they were stored on the disc. The data inside the ISO image will be structured according to the file system that was used on the optical disc from which it was created.

Since an ISO image is a sector-by-sector exact copy of a disk, the information as to whether or not it is bootable is stored within the file itself.

In other words, burn the ISO to a disk and attempt to boot from it. If it doesn't boot, then it wasn't intended to be used this way.

**Side note:** If you're attempting to create a bootable ISO using [CDBurnXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/) (my free disk creation software of choice) then you can do this from the *Disc -> Boot options..* menu which will bring up the following dialogue:

[image]

The [help page on the CDBurnXP website](https://cdburnerxp.se/help/Data/bootdisc) has some useful information on how to select a boot image and what the options mean.